# Is dataframe name required when using case_when inside mutate?

Tags: r, dplyr

```
full <- full %>% 
  mutate(Title = case_when(
    Title %in% c('Mlle', 'Ms') ~ 'Miss',
    Title == 'Mme' ~ 'Mrs',
    Title %in% rare_title ~ 'Rare Title',
    TRUE ~ Title
  ))
```

Code above gives an error: `Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : object 'Title' not found`

However, below code works. Is the data-frame name required inside case_when (makes the code more verbose).

```
full <- full %>% 
  mutate(Title = case_when(
    full$Title %in% c('Mlle', 'Ms') ~ 'Miss',
    full$Title == 'Mme' ~ 'Mrs',
    full$Title %in% rare_title ~ 'Rare Title',
    TRUE ~ full$Title
  ))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `.$` instead of calling `full$`

```
full <- full %>% 
          mutate(Title = case_when(
                 .$Title %in% c('Mlle', 'Ms') ~ 'Miss',
                  .$Title == 'Mme' ~ 'Mrs',
                   .$Title %in% rare_title ~ 'Rare Title',
                    TRUE ~ .$Title
             ))
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
full <- data.frame(Title = sample(c('Mlle', 'Ms', 'Mme', 'Colonel', 'Jr'), 20,
                 replace=TRUE), stringsAsFactors= FALSE)
rare_title <- 'Colonel'
```